# While Wend to search for all instances of a word in a list of words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I will have a list of words or phrases at the end of a document (each on a separate line). I want to search for each of those words in the document and applying yellow highlighting.

The process I'm trying to create:

1. Presume I am on the first word when I invoke the macro.
2. Evaluate the first character.
   If it's an empty line, do nothing and quit the macro.
   If there is a word or phrase, select it, store it as FRText.
3. Delete the line, create a bookmark, use F/R to find and highlight the text.
4. Repeat until there are no more words.

I have broken down the macro into single-step increments in temp macros, and I've also gotten the While...Wend statements to work with simpler "in between" steps (e.g., instead of a F/R operation, test for words vs. an empty line, and if words, bold the text, and if empty, quit).

When I put it all together in the same mayhem happens every time:
It compiles, but when I run it, I get a debug error. After I click on debug, it runs the macro on three or four words (correctly), and the debugger will stop at different random spots in the macro, with no hint as to what is wrong.

Also, if I perform the macro on the last word in the list, it works properly. And if I place the cursor on an empty line in the document, it also works properly (doing nothing, as it should).

I have searched for examples and information about While...Wend loops to see if I could find an explanation. I've also searched my books.

```vb
Sub FindAndHighlightList()
    
    Dim FRText As String
    Dim iCount As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    'Begin with cursor on first word in "find list."
    'Repeat the following action until no more words are found in the list
    'iCount is precautionary measure in case macro gets hung in the loop
    
    While Not Selection.Characters(1) = Chr(13) And iCount < 1000
        iCount = iCount + 1
            
        'Select the current line of text, minus the paragraph mark; store it as FRText; then delete it
        
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        
        FRText = Selection.Text
        
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        
        'Create a temporary bookmark
    
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
            .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="TempX"
            .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
            .ShowHidden = True
        End With
            
        'Find the selected text and replace add yellow highlight
        
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = FRText
            .Replacement.Text = FRText
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            
        'Go to TempX bookmark location
    
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="TempX"
    
    Wend
    
    If Selection.Characters(1) = Chr(13) Then Exit Sub
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

Sample text

> Here is an example of a paragraph with some words I want to highlight. And here are some more words. Here is an example of a paragraph with some words I want to highlight.
> And here are some more words. And I wish I could get this macro to work. Here is an example of a paragraph with some words I want to highlight. And here are some more words.
>
> Here
> example
> paragraph
> words
> macro

Comment: It sounds like you might be unaware that using `Find`, when the entire current selection is the exact text you are looking for, will look ahead to the next occurrence, even if that is earlier in the document. - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105332/5757159

Comment: Hi ThunderFrame -

Thanks for your response. I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying though. I do know that, for example, if I manually select some text and then invoke Find/Replace or Find, it will only search within that text, and it will search downward rather than from the beginning of the document.

GRRR -- keep hitting Enter! Anyway, that is why I set up the beginning of the macro the way I did - it selects the line of text, stores it as a variable, then deletes is - effectively deselecting it. Then it invokes F/R unencumbered. 

Does not that make a difference?

Comment: ThunderFrame, if you're thinking that could be a problem, maybe it wouldn't hurt to add a statement to go to the top of the document to start the search. I'll give that a try.

Comment: HOLY FREAKING COW!!!!!! I had to pick myself up off the floor just now. I cannot believe my eyes. After two LONNGGG days of screaming and cursing and sighing, I'm in disbelief that the fix was this simple!

THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, ThunderFrame. You are a hero. And thank you for the super-quick timeliness of your response as well. You have saved the day ... and my sanity! :):):)

Comment: I don't see any other voting options on this post other than tagging your comment as useful. Nor do I see any way to mark it as solved. What am I missing?

Comment: Glad I could help. Find is weird. Just upvote my answer in the linked post.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't see the option for upvoting. The only voting option I see is to vote for my own question as showing research effort or being clear. I don't see any option for upvoting the responses. If you can point me to it, I'll gladly do it!

Thanks also to YowE3K for editing and applying the formatting fix to my original question! :)

Comment: @ThunderFrame Post your solution as an "Answer" and the OP will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThunderFrame responded to my question with the following response:

It sounds like you might be unaware that using Find, when the entire current selection is the exact text you are looking for, will look ahead to the next occurrence, even if that is earlier in the document

And it worked!

I'm posting his answer here because I did not see any options for upvoting his comment and marking the question as solved. So hopefully, this gives me the option to do that.

Thanks so much, ThunderFrame!